# Ms Access - VBA - Create Labels Programatically with Size

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to create `Labels & Textboxes` and assign some values to it dynamically, depending on the variable count `NoOfRecords`(The problem is that I don't know in advance how many controls I'll need. The number will be driven by how many records there are in a particular table).
My Form name is `frmDashboard`

**What I tried is**

```
Set cNN = Nothing
Set rsfnum = Nothing
Dim strconnfnum As String
Set cNN = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rsfnum = New ADODB.Recordset

strconnfnum = "SELECT nz(employeename,'') as employeename from employees"
rsfnum.Open strconnfnum, cNN, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

'Number of Records in Employees tables

NoOfRecords = rsfnum.RecordCount


    For x = 1 To NoOfRecords
        Set ctrl = CreateControl("frmDashboard", acLabel, acDetail, , "", 0 + (x * 300), 0, 300, 240)
        ctrl.ControlName = "lblDynamic_control_" & x
       Controls("lblDynamic_control_" & x).Caption = x
        Set ctrl1 = CreateControl("frmDashboard", acTextBox, acDetail, , "", 0 + (x * 300), 0, 300, 240)
        ctrl1.ControlName = "txtDynamic_control_" & x  
       Controls("txtDynamic_control_" & x).Value= x
    Next x
```

**There are 2 issues i am facing here**
**1) How to show label and textboxes one after another like below 
(Next Label and Textbox should be exactly below the top.)**

[image]

**2) The above code throws the following error**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is correct and cannot be overcome when you eventually distribute your DB as a compiled, split database.

The trick here is going to be to create all the controls you could possibly need ahead of time. You'll need to label then and have them be in order on the form. So like `Text1`, `Text2`, `Label`, `Label2`. This way you can loop through each of the textbox/label combo by their index (which will be the index of your field in your recordset).

[image]

```
Private Function ReBindControls()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset 'if you are using ADO then replace this with ADODB.Recordset 
    If IsNull(Combo99) Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Combo99) ' If you are using ADO use the appropriate ADO method to open the recordset

    Dim fs As DAO.Fields 'if you are using ADO then replace this with ADODB.Fields
    Set fs = rs.Fields

    Dim f As Integer
    Dim aLabel As Label, aTextBox As TextBox

    Set Me.Recordset = rs

    For f = 0 To fs.Count - 1
        Set aLabel = Controls("Label" & f)
        aLabel.Caption = fs(f).Name
        aLabel.Visible = True

        Set aTextBox = Controls("text" & f)
        aTextBox.ControlSource = fs(f).Name
        aTextBox.Visible = True

        aLabel.Move 1 * 1440, f * 1440 / 2
        aTextBox.Move 2.5 * 1440, f * 1440 / 2
    Next f

End Function


Function clearBindings()
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim aLabel As Label, aTextBox As TextBox

    For c = 0 To maxIndexOfControls
        Set aTextBox = Controls("text" & c)
        aTextBox.ControlSource = ""
        Set aLabel = Controls("Label" & c)
        aLabel.Visible = False
        aTextBox.Visible = False
        aLabel.Move 0, 0
        aTextBox.Move 0, 0

    Next c
End Function
```

If you call both of these together

```
Private Sub Combo99_Change()
    clearBindings
    ReBindControls
End Sub
```

you can get these results

[image]
[image]

Comment: i tried to execute  your code its throwing me an error; i have updated my code to the actual query i  am using, the connection strings etc.; can you please answer/code to fit in my db connection. The error is at http://prntscr.com/9ftssa

Comment: I made some additions. Also I didn't know you were using ADO. My code uses DAO. Basically you can replace my DAO references with your ADO references. I'll make an edit to reflect that

Comment: you'll notice in my screenshot I have a combobox to switch recordsets. If you don't have that then it will throw an exception. You'll need to adjust this to your own situation.

Comment: ok, do you have that sample MDB  that yo can share and I can refer and try to figure out my issue.

Comment: sorry  i am newbie to access so trying to figure it out

Comment: My employee table has only 2 fields employee id and employeename so depending on the recordcount i want to display employee id on lable and employee name on textbox.. dynamically

Comment: @user580950 You want to have each of these text boxes show different records? What I am demonstrating is how to dynamically manipulate your form based on the recordset definition. I'll have to add another answer

Comment: Depending on the Recordcount (a) dynamically create number of labels & textboxes (b) place those under each other as per my diagram

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98379/discussion-between-user580950-and-brad).

Answer (score 0):

OK - disclaimer I'm a complete newbie here - but I looked into this and apparently VBA won't let you create controls (i.e. the 'set ctrl' or 'set ctrl1' commands) at runtime. Those have to be created at design time and made visible based on the dynamic input at runtime.

If there's a max value for NoOfRecords I might suggest pre-coding ALL of the possible ctrls (using a loop) at design-time and making the number that become visible/active based on the dynamic input at runtime.

As for organizing the layout of labels and textboxes, that would also be done as a part of that designing loop. As noted in the documentation below, the placement of the upper-left corner of each ctrl can be specified in the CreateControl method in the 'left' and 'top' commands (you have it currently as left = 0+(x*300), top = 0 ). Just add the necessary adjustments to x-and-y coordinates as you iterate through ctrl creation.

CreateControl method documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221167%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Hope that helps!

Comment: as I said in my question precoding all the controls is not possible as those are dynamic record count. And VBA lets create control, where do you see it doesn't let you to create control